# Access model object in admin.StackedInline inline

Tags: django, admin, inline

I am trying to use an `inline` in `UserAdmin` in `admin.py`
I am looking for a way to modify the fields of that `inline` based on the object.

### ProfileInline

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    filter_horizontal = ('user_markets',)
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False
    fields = ('email_role', )
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
```

### UserAdmin

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', roles, login)
    list_filter = ('groups',)
    inlines = (ProfileInline,)
```

Here I need to modify `ProfileInline.fields = ('department','email_role')` if the user belongs to the `Sales` `Group`, else whatever.

I need a way to access the user `Object` and update the `fields`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    filter_horizontal = ('user_markets',)
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False
    fields = ('email_role', )
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(ProfileInline, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

        # fieldsets[0][1]['fields'].remove('email_role')
        fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = ('department', 'email_role')

        return fieldsets
```

`get_fieldsets` method is your solution. You have `request` object so `request.user` also.