# Display a model field as readonly in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I want to display a model field ie `module_name` as read only in django user profile edit page. The model `Category` has a `manytomany` relationship with `Profile` model.

`Category`

```
id   category_name module_name
1    A             X
2    B             Y
```

`profile_category`

```
id    profile_id    category_id
1     2             1
```

So for eg. when I am on the admin page to editing a user id of `2` then I would like to display the module name `X` if category id `1` is assigned to the user id `2`

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=True, default="", unique=True)
    module_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ='profile')
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

`admin.py`

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    filter_horizontal = ('category',)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_select_related = ( 'profile',  )
```

Please suggest if this is possible or not.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1

Use [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) which is inherited from `admin.BaseModelAdmin`.

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    readonly_fields = ('module_names',)

    def module_names(self, instance):
        # Write a get-method for a list of module names in the class Profile
        # return HTML string which will be display in the form
        return format_html_join(
              mark_safe('<br/>'),
              '{}',
              ((line,) for line in instance.get_module_names()),
        ) or mark_safe("<span>The user belongs to no category</span>")

    # short_description functions like a model field's verbose_name
    module_names.short_description = "Module names"
```

## Method 2

For older versions of `admin` site, you can hook the `get_fieldsets` method of `admin.StackedInline`. This method was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803980/6238076) with a nice example.

Comment: Many thanks. Struggling to get the module names inside class `Profile`. I am trying to retrieve the values from profile_category & category table. The query should be `select module_name from category,profile_category where profile_category.profile_id = 2 and category.id = profile_category.category_id`

Comment: This (Method 1) hides the field from admin display completely. At least under Django 2.0